# Show unique/returning user count on my website

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, web, analytics

I am working on the admin dashboard of my website and I was wondering if there is a way to display unique or returning user count. 
Can I link/fetch my google analytics return value in any way possible. 
This way the admin does not necessarily needs to go to Google Analytics, simply logon to the website and have the information readily available.

Answer (score 0):

If you need historical data i think that the easiest way to do that is using the embed api
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/

With that you can create easyly some chart to be embed on you html page, if yu can handle you can use the api.

Now,If you want to do it with the realtime report( the analytics module), it's not possible, because that metric is not available on that plataform